# Передача сигнала запущенному приложению при старте нового экземпляра

Tags: c#, wpf

Написал, приложение, единовременно может существовать один экземпляр которого:

```
bool existed;
string guid = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();

Mutex mutexObj = new Mutex(true, guid, out existed);

if (existed)
{
   var application = new App();
   application.InitializeComponent();
   application.Run();
}
```

Но как мне уведомить уже запущенное приложение (если, конечно такое есть), что второй его экземпляр пытался запуститься?

На ум приходят только какие-нить костыли, типа создавать файл и в основном экземпляре программы постоянно проверять его существование, есть ли что-либо более грамотное?

Comment: Можно использовать NamedPipe. Кстати, пайп и мутекс заменить может. Кстати: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777668/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это действительно именно то, чего я добивался. Спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в целом решение правильное, но вот только я не могу переопределить WndProc, пишет, что просто нет такого метода. Я не на WF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать сообщение WM_COPYDATA:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;                        
            public IntPtr lpData;
        }

        const uint WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;        

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {   
            if (msg == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                COPYDATASTRUCT data = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, data.GetType());                
                MessageBox.Show("Received command: "+Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.lpData));                 
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 

            Process this_process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();            

            //найти все процессы с таким же именем
            Process[] other_processes =
                Process.GetProcessesByName(this_process.ProcessName).Where(pr => pr.Id != this_process.Id).ToArray();

            foreach (var pr in other_processes)
            {
                pr.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //на случай, если процесс еще не загрузился

                //берем первый процесс с окном
                IntPtr hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) continue;

                //отправляем команду
                string command = "Hello";
                var cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;
                cds.cbData = (command.Length + 1) * 2;
                cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(command);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cds.lpData);

                //завершаем работу
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            //если ничего не найдено, продолжаем работу             
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений            
        }
    }
}
```