# Вывод путей нескольких выделенных файлов в проводнике через программу C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Я бы хотел, чтобы когда ты выделяешь несколько например фотографий в проводнике и нажимаешь "Открыть", то открывалась бы программа, в которой можно было бы работать с информацией об этих файлах.

Пытался уже реализовать такое, но выделив несколько файлов открывалось несколько окон программы.

Сделал небольшую доработку

App.xaml.cs

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int cbData;
    public IntPtr lpData;
}
public const uint WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    Process this_process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    Process[] other_processes =
    Process.GetProcessesByName(this_process.ProcessName).Where(pr => pr.Id != this_process.Id).ToArray();

    foreach (var pr in other_processes)
    {
         pr.WaitForInputIdle(1000);
         IntPtr hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
         if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) continue;
         string command = e.Args[0] + " " + e.Args.Length;
         var cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
         cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;
         cds.cbData = (command.Length + 1) * 2;
         cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(command);
         SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
         Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cds.lpData);
         Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

И MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
     if (msg == WM_COPYDATA)
     {
         COPYDATASTRUCT data = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
         data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, data.GetType());
         MessageBox.Show("Received command: " + Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.lpData));
     }

     return IntPtr.Zero;
}
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
     HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
     source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений      
}
```

И все хорошо в принципе, т.к. когда я кликаю по картинке (при открытом окне программы) то выводится в MessageBox.Show ее путь. Но проблема теперь в том, что если я выберу несколько картинок и нажму открыть то раньше бы открылось столько экземпляров сколько картинок. А сейчас MessageBox.Show выведет только путь той картинки которая была выбрана первой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88916/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда пользователь открывает в проводнике несколько файлов, проводник создает несколько процессов примерно в один момент времени. Однако, от старта процесса до момента, когда окно будет готово к приему сообщений, проходит некоторое время. Поэтому нужно несколько модифицировать [способ с WM_COPYDATA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936446/240512), чтобы он смог обработать эту ситуацию: добавить ожидание создания окна в основном процессе, избегать использования MessageBox, так как он блокирует выполнение, и т.д.

Класс Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApp1
{

    public partial class App : Application
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr lpData;
        }

        public const uint WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            string command = "";
            string[] argv = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (argv.Length > 1)
                command = argv[1];

            Process this_process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Process main_process;

            //найти все процессы с таким же именем, запущенные ранее данного процесса
            Process[] other_processes =
                Process.GetProcessesByName(this_process.ProcessName)
                .Where(pr => { return pr.Id != this_process.Id && pr.StartTime <= this_process.StartTime;})
                .OrderBy((pr) => { return pr.StartTime; })
                .ToArray();

            //найти основной процесс
            if (other_processes.Length > 0) main_process = other_processes[0];
            else return;

            //ждем создания окна в основном процессе
            IntPtr hWnd;
            int c = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                hWnd = main_process.MainWindowHandle;
                if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) break;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                c++;
                if (c > 10) { return; }
            }

            //отправляем команду
            var cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;
            cds.cbData = (command.Length + 1) * 2;
            cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(command);
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cds.lpData);

            //завершаем работу
            Environment.Exit(0);    
        }        
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" Margin="10,46,0,0"
                 x:Name="tbFilename"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="427"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {                     

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == App.WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                App.COPYDATASTRUCT data = new App.COPYDATASTRUCT();
                data = (App.COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, data.GetType());
                tbFilename.Text += Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.lpData)+";";                
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] argv = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (argv.Length > 1)
                tbFilename.Text += argv[1] + ";";            
        }        


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код и возникло пару вопросов. 1) Я использую паттерн MVVM и для открытия окон использую следующую систему
            MainViewModel = new MainViewModel(e.Args);
            DisplayRootRegistry.ShowPresentation(MainViewModel);
Вы наверно видели уже такое. И получается в App.xaml в параметре StartupUri у меня его вообще нет. Как соединить их? Я попробовал добавить код выше написанный перед Exit(0) но процесс был а окна не было. И 2 я добавил StartupUri и открывалось несколько окон. Может я что-то не то вставил? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @ПавелЕриков т.е. вам нужно выполнить некоторые дополнительные действия в Application_Startup, так чтобы они выполнялись только для основного экземпляра? В таком случае вам нужно после `if (other_processes.Length > 0) main_process = other_processes[0];` заменить  `else return;` на `else {InitializeApp(); return;}` и поместить эти действия в метод InitializeApp.

Comment: Да я разобрался уже спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вот последний вопрос тк я использую MVVM мне нужно как-то в VM передавать эти пути. У меня из нормальных идей сделать массив в VM static и туда добавлять пути

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, сделайте в vm метод для добавления путей и просто вызывайте его с параметром. Только имейте ввиду, что добавлять путь в коллекцию нужно обязательно в контексте GUI, т. к. сообщения могут придти в любом потоке

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да, раз этот список один на все приложение, логично использовать static массив и обернуть его в метод AddPath для добавления и get-only свойство, которое уже привязывать к контролам

Comment: Пожалуйста поподробней. Я сделал метод статический по добавлению в список путей но почему то не добавляется.

Comment: То что я написал ниже tbFileName.Text += argv[1] то вообще похоже не читается. Тк после этой строки я добавил добавление путя в список. А потом также tbFileName.Text += "Путь отправлен" но кроме путя файла ничего не добавляется